# Qt creator 4 cannot find QCamera

Tags: c++, linux, qt, include, qt-creator

I want to use QCamera, but Qt Creator 4.0.1 with Qt 5.6.1 says that such files do not exist, when I'm trying to include it:

```
#include <QtMultimedia/QCamera>
```

I've tried it also without the QtMultimedia/ beforehand. And also autocomplition menu.
My System is Debian Testing. This is a C++11 project.
My Project.pro file looks like this:

```
    QT       += core gui opengl multimedia

    greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

    TARGET = Classifier
    TEMPLATE = app

    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
    [..]
```

I have deleted QT += multimediawidgets, because QT warns, that it is unknown.
Although libqt5multimediawidgets5 is installed. Or do I need more packages for that? 
I have tried the following:

- I have rerun qmake,
- Closed Qt Creator, deleted Project.pro.user and reconfigured the project
- Checked if all packages are installed - I hope so. qtmultimedia5-dev qt5base-dev. And libqt5multimediawidgets5 ... Would be to long, to list all, which does not mean, that I have all necessary ones.
- Added the options QT_SELECT=qt5 and QTDIR=/usr/share/qt5 qmake --version to the project.pro file. Found it in some stackoverflow answer where a user guessed you could use that to enforce qt5. Because I wasn't sure, if it doesn't use Qt4. But the options do not even get highlighted. But not marked as errors either.
- Tried to write 'class QCamera' to my mainwindow.h and include QCamera in the mainwindow.cpp file as seen in a Youtube tutorial
- Tried the Camera Example Project, which doesn't work either
- Checked, if Qt5 is available in the options menu

As mentioned, I have also Qt4 stuff installed. I have also an old project, which was set up in Windows and uses QCamera. There Qt Creator cannot find it either.
If this does not work anyway on Debian for some reason, what is an alternative -compatible with Qt?

Comment: There might be other problems, but your include style is wrong. You want only `#include <QCamera>`.

Comment: if the Camera example doesn't work, I think that there is a problem with your Qt installation.

Comment: @KubaOber To quote myself: "QtMultimedia/ beforehand".

Comment: @Mike Yes, quite probably, but what exactly could be wrong? I just installed everything with apt-get install X

Comment: To correct my first comment: I forgot the "without the" at the beginning of the quote

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 with qt5-base, qtcreator and qtmultimedia5-dev recognizes it. And there was an error in the ui mainwindow.h which occurs, if you use a qt4 project with qt5. So it used qt4 on Debian, even though qt5 is installed. But I have no idea how I can enforce qt5 in Qt Creator. So it seems to be a Qt Creator problem. This is actually no direct solution, but it works now (for me). But if anyone knows how to enforce qt5, I would appriciate it. Because Ubuntu is only a workaround

Comment: You have full control over what kit you're currently building your project with. If you have multiple Qt versions installed, you can add each one to Qt creator as its own kit, and you can select what kits you want to make available to build the project with. What you describe should never be a problem. E.g. I'm building multiple projects with multiple versions of Qt - some are Qt 4, some are Qt 5.